# What is AmbientClass?

Tags: c#, attributes

What is the use of an AmbientClassAttribute whose definition is as below (in C#):

```
using System;

namespace Metamodel
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class AmbientClassAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.ambientattribute.aspx

Comment: @daryal: Thank you for the link. It is complicated language out there. Can you simplify it for me. I don't understand why the class has no members. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AmbientClassAttribute` is, as the name implies an attribute class, which means it's used as an attribute on a class definition, like this:

```
[AmbientClass]
public class MyClass { }
```

All this does is add metadata - it marks the class as an AmbientClass - whatever that means. But the act of marking itself - the adding of the attribute - doesn't have any logic behind it, which is why the class doesn't have any members. It doesn't *do* anything. It just marks the class as an Ambient Class.

What *is* it good for, then? It allows other pieces of code, code that goes over my class - in this case XAML processors - to know about this metadata and process accordingly:
"XAML processors [use this to] determine type owners of members".

Comment: Thank you for a simple explanation. Could you please elaborate on "XAML processors [use this to] determine type owners of members" especially the "type owners" part

Comment: I took that from the class's MSDN documentation. It's an attribute that's used as part of WPF's XAML parsing. Why do you need to know that?

Comment: I am going through some code written by others, and trying to understand the concepts.

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I know. I'd try going over the MSDN documentation of the rest of the System.Windows.Markup namespace, or maybe googling it up.